# Regex with multiple groups, some of which are optional

Tags: regex, knime

I have trouble matching multiple groups, some of which are optional. I've tried variations of greedy/non greedy, but can't get it to work.

As input, I have cells which look like this:

```
SEPA Overboeking                 IBAN: AB1234        BIC: LALA678                    Naam: John Smith            Omschrijving: Hello hello        Kenmerk: 03-05-2019 23:12 533238
```

I wanna split these up into groups of IBAN, BIC, Naam, Omschrijving, Kenmerk.

For this example, this yields: AB1234; LALA678; John Smith; Hello hello; 03-05-2019 23:12 533238.
To obtain this, I've used:

```
.*IBAN: (.*)\s+BIC: (.*)\s+Naam: (.*)\s+Omschrijving: (.*)\s+Kenmerk: (.*)
```

This works perfectly as long as all these groups are present in the input. Some cells, however don't have the "Omschrijving" and/or "Kenmerk" part. As output, I would like to have empty groups if they're not present. Right now, nothing is matched.
I've tried variations with greedy/non greedy, but couldn't get it to work.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

N.B.:  I'm working in KNIME (open source data analysis tool)

Comment: You can split on 2 or more whitespaces or make some capturing groups optional.

Comment: Tried that too, unfortunately sometimes there's only 1 whitespace in between the elements

Comment: Are the fields always in the same order?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yes they are

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to split your input using the following regular expression:

```
^.*
\s+IBAN\:\s*(?<IBAN>.*?)
\s+BIC\:\s*(?<BIC>.*?)
\s+Naam\:\s*(?<Naam>.*?)
(?:\s+Omschrijving\:\s*(?<Omschrijving>.*?))?
(?:\s+Kenmerk\:\s*(?<Kenmerk>.*?))?
$
```

This requires your fields to follow the given order and will treat the fields `IBAN`, `BIC` and `Naam` as required. Fields `Omschrijving` and `Kenmerk` may be optional. I am pretty sure, this can still be optimized, but it results in the following output, which should be fine for you (or at least a starting point):

[image: Example output results]

For evaluation and testing in KNIME, I used Palladian's [Regex Extractor](https://nodepit.com/node/ws.palladian.nodes.extraction.regex.RegexExtractorNodeFactory) node, that can be configured as follows and provides a nice preview functionality:

[image: Regex Extractor configuration]

I added an example workflow to my [NodePit Space](https://nodepit.com/workflow/com.nodepit.space%2Fdaniel%2Fpublic%2Fforum%2Fregex-with-multiple-groups-some-of-which-are-optional-62131566.knwf). It contains some example lines, parses them and provides the above seen output.

Comment: Wow, amazing! Thanks so much for the extensive reply. Also great  tip to use the regex extractor tool, I'll check it out. What are the functions called where you start a group with a question mark? And the use of <>? Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! The `(?:group)` construct are "non-capturing groups" I just use to make those groups optional. The `(?<name>group)` construct is called a "named capturing group". It allows back references by name, but is also used by the Regex Extractor node to name the extracted columns. Pretty handy and avoids using a Column Rename node afterwards.